# Installing python-daemon

Tags: python, python-daemon

I've downloaded the python-daemon package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/) and tried installing it using

```
python setup.py install
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 22, in ?
     main_module = __import__(main_module_name, fromlist=['version'])
TypeError: __import__() takes no keyword arguments
```

I'm not sure what's causing this. I tried getting around it by just working in same directory as the downloaded module (in which case I can get access to the daemon module), but that led to other problems down the line.

Also, I'm using python 2.4.3, and updating is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: i think this is a feature of newer versions python, and will not work with 2.4 as you have experienced

Comment: A workaround might be to remove the "`, fromlist=['version']`" from the `__import__()` function call and add a `version = main_module.version` statement after it because that's essentially what it does.

Comment: Thanks, I believe the problem is with the older version of python 2.4.

Comment: I understand that. My suggestion is about a possible way to make the setup.py code do the something equivalent using the older version you're trying to use that doesn't take keyword arguments.

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo pip install python-daemon
```

Comment: `sudo pip install python-daemon` works both in ubuntu and mac.